# How to script sql server database diagrams in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, generate-scripts

I use sql server 2005 as my database for my web application.... I generated scripts of the database by,

`Database->Right Click->Tasks->Generate Scripts`

I can script all my `Tables,Stored Procedures,User Defined functions,Views,Users....`

All i missed was `database diagrams` because there was no option for scripting it.. How to include them into the new database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ScriptDiagram2005.aspx).